# Inserção da letra "e" em type number

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber como não permitir a inserção da letra "*e*", que provavelmente representa o número de [Euler](http://www.educ.fc.ul.pt/icm/icm99/icm17/numeroe.htm), no input `type="number`.

Comment: Acredito que esse "e" aí representa a notação científica, indicando a potência de 10. Por quê não permitir que ele seja indicado no campo?

Comment: Como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse, [pelo que pude ler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706796/3956218), a letra "e" nada tem a ver com o número de euler, e sim pela característica do `input type="number"` aceitar números com a notação científica, [arrisque aumentar ou diminuir 1](https://jsfiddle.net/xmdvdbf3/), ele tambem aceita números negativos, ou seja ele aceita os dois caracteres "e" e "-", além dos 10 algarismos do sistema decimal

Comment: Resumindo, ao invés de digitar  `10000`, o usuário pode digitar `1e4`, o que simplifica para quem conhece a notação científica - ainda mais quando considerado números ainda maiores. Agora, se você não deseja manter a notação, basta utilizar [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Sinceramente, eu não vejo motivos algum para impedir algo que facilita a vida do usuário.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Depende muito do sistema. Eu vejo muitas formas pela qual permitir notação científica apenas criaria uma bagunça. Isso depende muito de para onde esse dado será enviado e como será processado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encontrei algo parecido [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715052/4551469):

```
var valorNum = document.getElementById("id_input")

valorNum.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  // prevent: "e"
  if ([69].includes(e.keyCode)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Um ponto que você precisa ver é que ao chegar no valor máximo do campo e o usuário clicar na setinha (cima ou baixo) ele transforma o número e exibe o *"e"* (ex: `2.18723978932187987e+35`), mas este código previne a letra e caracteres especiais digitados pelo usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer seria assim, no seu HTML:

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="return FilterInput(event)" onpaste="handlePaste(event)">
```

E no seu JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function FilterInput(event) {
        var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

        isNotWanted = (keyCode == 69 || keyCode == 101);
        return !isNotWanted;
    };

    function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text').toUpperCase();

        if(pastedData.indexOf('E')>-1) {
            //alert('found an E');
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar desta forma, aonde **#input** seria o id do seu input:

Em Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 0 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            $(".alert").html("Enter only digits!").show().fadeOut(2000);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Em Javascript puro:

```
document.querySelector(".your_class").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.which != 8 && evt.which != 0 && evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Poderia ter incluído a fonte na resposta.

Comment: Poderia claro mas ai colocaria todos os locais aonde pesquisei para encontrar, tem uma junção de algumas respostas. E @Henrique caso tenha uma resposta exatamente igual pode marcar a fonte. Ou poderia colocar sua resposta. Ou melhor pedir para cada pessoa adicionar suas fontes, pois todas as respostas daqui vieram de outros lugares né ?

Comment: Na verdade só comentei porque são as mesmas respostas desta pergunta: [How to block +,-,e in input type Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291997/how-to-block-e-in-input-type-number)

Comment: Entendi e fato são iguais porém não as encontrei ali. Mas se for assim concordamos que deveria colocar o mesmo comentario em praticamente todas as respostas aqui do SO né.